# Incorrect number of probabilities

Tags: r

```
Arrivals <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4), size=1, prob = c(.15,.25,.3,.2,.1),replace = TRUE)
Buyers <- sample(Arrivals, size=1, prob = .6, replace = TRUE)
```

I want to take a sample of a sample.

Here Arrivals give me back a single integer. Yet I still get the error

```
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

I found many answers on here that say that X and Prob need to be the same length and is the typical reason for the error.

But X (Arrivals) and the Prob are the same length and I still get the error.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a single numeric value `x` into `sample()`, it thinks you want to sample from 1 to `x`.  That's why it is telling you that you have the wrong number of probabilities in your second `sample()` call for `Buyers`.

For example, if `Arrival` is set to 2, then calling `sample(Arrivals)` is saying "I want to sample from `c(1, 2)`.  But you only provide one probability, instead of two - that's why you get the error.

```r
set.seed(123)
Arrivals <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4), size=1, prob = c(.15,.25,.3,.2,.1), replace = TRUE) # returns 2

Buyers <- sample(Arrivals, size=1, prob = c(.6, .4), replace = TRUE) # runs without error
```

From the `sample` [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html):

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x. Note that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in calls such as sample(x). See the examples.

Comment: But it is the same probability for all Arrivals.

Comment: You asked why you are getting the error.  This is why you are getting the error - the R function `sample()` works differently than you might normally expect when you pass in a single value.  The probabilities of the `Arrivals` values do not matter - this is a syntax issue with the `sample()` function.

Comment: @andrew_reece Try `set.seed(42)`, your answer might be incorrect.